# Clean builds with Multibranch Workflow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Using Multibranch Workflow, the command to check out looks like

```
checkout scm
```

I can't find a way to tell Jenkins to perform a clean checkout. By "clean," I mean it should remove all files from the workspace that aren't under version control.

Comment: I don't know whether `checkout` can take further parameters in multibranch. I imagine there is a more elegant solution, but if you're using Git, you should be able to run `sh 'git clean -fdx'` after the `checkout` step.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers the original question or not (I couldn't tell if the intention was to leave some files in the workspace) but why not just remove the workspace first, this would allow a clean checkout:

```
stage ('Clean') {
    deleteDir()
}

stage ('Checkout') {
    checkout scm 
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that you could just do a `sh 'git clean -fdx'` after checkout instead of deleting everything as @christopher-orr suggested

Answer (score 12):

I run into the same problem and here is my workaround.
I created a new scm object for the checkout and extended the extensions with the CleanBeforeCheckout. But i kept the other configurations like branches and userRemoteConfigs.

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: scm.branches,
    extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']],
    userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
])
```

It's still not perfect because you have to create a new object :(

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Deleting the complete directory is not always appropriate when you just want to do a git clean.

Comment: And do we directly add this in jenkinsfile?

Comment: Yeah, to any pipeline script. It was 2 years ago but i think this should still work :)

Comment: Script will require approval to access `SCM` parameters, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can not assume that a workflow job has a workspace as it was for freestyle jobs. Actually, a workflow job can use more than one workspace (one for each `node` or `ws` block).

Said that, what I'm going to propose is a kind of hacky: modify the scm object before checkout to set up a `CleanCheckout` extension (you will have to approve some calls there).

```
import hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.CleanCheckout
scm.extensions.replace(new CleanCheckout())
checkout scm
```

But I'd prefer Christopher Orr's proposal, use a shell step after `checkout` (`sh 'git clean -fdx'`).

Comment: Thanks for that. The problem with both suggestions is that it only works with Git.

Comment: There are equivalents for most SCM implementations. For example, for subversion you can use `scm.setWorkspaceUpdater(new UpdateWithCleanUpdater())`

Comment: Where can I find the documentation on these things? (I'm using Hg.)

Comment: There is no documentation for that, they are low level details and you have to check the source code to get it.

Comment: what do you think about @TomDotTom's proposal in the other answer?

Comment: Well, that's basically not correct for Multibranch Pipelines, where you already have the `scm` object created. Adding that new `checkout` step would add another `scm` object to the build and it has side effects (like duplicated changelog entries in the build page).

Answer (score 1):

[image: workflow behavior]

Behaviors can be added when configuring the source.  `clean before checkout`, `clean after checkout` and `Wipe out repository and force clone`.  This removes the need to add logic to the declarative / scripted pipelines.

Comment: This may only happen on the master branch and not the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [Christopher-Orr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234938/christopher-orr)'s comment as an answer to just do:

```
stage('Checkout') {
  checkout scm
  sh 'git clean -fdx'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins currently contains a page to generate groovy pipeline syntax. Selecting the checkout step you should be able to add all the additional options that you're used to.

I generated the following which should do what you want:

```
checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://repo/location.git']]]
```

Comment: This answer only works on normal Pipeline job but doesn't work on Multibranch Pipeline job.